# Radio Button value not get in android Devices

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, radio-button

Am working in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap.
Currently am facing a small issue but couldnt resolved yet in Mobile Devices.
But its working well in browsers.

My Iussue is ; I have three radio buttons ; and when I select anyone of the Radio button 
i want to get the value of that radiobutton.

Here My Code

**HTML**

```
        <div class="radio">  
           <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rr" data-role="none" value="mr"/>
           <label for="r1" style="margin-left:0px;"><span></span>Mr</label> 
           <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rr" data-role="none" value="mrs"/>
           <label for="r2"><span></span>Mrs</label> 
           <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rr" data-role="none" value="ms"/>
           <label for="r3"><span></span>Ms</label> 
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .radio {
  margin-top:20px;
  height:30px;
  } 
  .radio input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
  }

 .radio input[type="radio"] + label {
  color:#000;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left:10px; 
  }

 .radio input[type="radio"] + label span {
  display:inline-block;
  width:19px;
  height:19px;
  margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:url(../images/radio.png) no-repeat;
  background-position:bottom;
  cursor:pointer;
  }

  .radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
   background:url(../images/radio.png) no-repeat;
  background-position:top;
  }
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $("#btn_test").tap(function(event){

          var ak = $('input:radio[name=rr]:checked').val();
          alert(ak);

    });
```

**Its Working in Browsers.** But not in Eclipse Simulators 
When We alert we get a null value.

I think its a small issue.. but still I didnt get a solution for this. :(

Comment: not sure if this could be an issue, but you could try with `$('input:radio[name="rr"]:checked').val();`

Comment: @Spokey I tried that code also.. but in browsers its OK

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V - I tried your code in my mobile device and it's working correctly.

Comment: instead of `tap` try this `$('[type=radio]').on('change', function () { $(this).val(); });` as in here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NKDTF/

Comment: @Omar I think he wants to get the value of the radio button on click k of a button..

Comment: @Omar : yeah.. i need valus in button click

Comment: Replace `tap` with `vclick` as in this example. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NKDTF/